# Trying to position div at bottom of mobile viewport, not bottom of browser

Tags: javascript, css, touch

I've got a div that I want to position at the bottom of the mobile browser (Safari + Android) viewport. Currently my div is fixed at the bottom on all the top 5 browsers on Windows (IE, FF, Saf, Chrome, Opera), but that's "the browser window", not "the viewport".

On mobile devices (I've only tried on Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 2.2 so far) the div appears at the bottom of the page, but if you pinch/punch to zoom in, the fixed div doesn't follow. It stays behind, outside of the viewport.

I'm specifically using the position:fixed and bottom:0 CSS properties to maintain the position, and as I said, it works fine on a non-touch browser.

Am I going to have to resort to keeping the div in the position I'd like it to be (at the bottom of the viewport) by hooking into the touchmove event and looking at (a) the zoom level, (b) the viewport position, and (c) the scroll position?

I'm using JavaScript to inject the div into the page rather than using inline CSS. The good thing is that I don't have to worry about quirks mode (as I'm only targeting Webkit browsers), so that's one positive thing.

I can't set doctype, use inline CSS or inline DIVs. Everything has to be added dynamically via JavaScript. Here's what I've done in my test so far:

```
var mydiv=document.createElement("div");
mydiv.style.position="fixed";
mydiv.style.bottom="0px";
mydiv.id="floater";
mydiv.style.width="400px";
mydiv.style.height="50px";
mydiv.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
if(document.body)document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
document.getElementById("floater").innerHTML="HELLO";
```

Comment: May be worthwhile looking at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) and seeing how they keep the tool-bars fixed. You also use @media to apply different CSS based on the client's settings viewing the screen.

Comment: Thanks Brad on the two jQ~ tips, I'm looking into them. What do you mean by "@media" though?

Comment: What Brad is referring to is Media Queries: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/ Definitely worth looking in to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your `position:fixed` won't work on mobile webkit browsers.** Take a look at [the mobile webkit fixed position problem](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/the-mobile-webkit-css-fixed-position-problem/) on http://www.position-absolute.com/. They have a few ways of keeping something at the bottom.

Comment: That's another one that's based on iScroll, which seems (to me) to be all about how to scroll within a div.

Comment: @Dee2000 You misunderstand.  Safari webkit does not support `position:fixed` and it also doesn't scroll the site, it scrolls the window.  These scripts (and there were two in that link, you neglected Pastry Kit) recreating scrolling and other features so that you can implement a javascript version of `position:fixed`.

Comment: Thanks @Levi I downloaded the pastry kit and will look into it. I just caught a break though. Turns out we don't want this feature anymore. If it comes back, hopefully there'll be a nice new standard-ish way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out **iScroll**:
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

It seems to be one of the better options out there - definitely worth looking into.

I have used the previous version of iScroll but unfortunately there were a few things that didn't work to standard so we had to scrap the idea. However, the guys at Cubiq have just released v4 of iScroll which promises to fix a lot of the things that were issues in the previous version.

Best of luck!
Dan

Comment: I had looked at iScroll before I made my post. It just seemed to be all about creating content that allowed you to scroll the contents within a div. I don't want to "scroll my div", I want mine to stay in a fixed visible position and not be scrolled. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The way iScroll works is, it allows you to set a 'scrollable' area while making either the header and/or footer fixed. So the 'Scrollable' area is the viewport in which the user can scroll through while the header and or footer stay in their fixed position. It works differently to desktop websites in the sense that you don't set the footer to be fixed but rather you set the area that will be scrollable.